# Como iterar uma url no Javascript

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho uma `tag img` e necessito iterar o `src`, alterando dentro de um `map` a `uri`.

**ex:** `../assets/images/personagens/${index}.jpg`, cujo index é o parâmetro do `map`, porém o **javascript** não permite esta ação dentro de um `require(url)`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: O que já tentou?

Comment: @Matheus Maricondi te importas em mostrar o que você já tentou, talvez isso possa ajudar a compreender melhor  a tua pergunta. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi bem o seu objetivo.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var indexes = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("images")
  x.innerHTML = indexes.map((currentValue, index) => {
    var uri = '../assets/images/personagens/${currentValue}.jpg'
    return `<img src="{uri}">`
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Clique no Botão para gerar imagens</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Criar Imagens</button>

<div id="images"></div>

</body>
</html>
```